# I need help opening a Hidden Batch file with VBS

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to start a batch file that will be hidden, to keep a program from installing itself onto my computer, here is my VBScript:

```
set WshShell = wscript.createobject("WScript.shell")
WshShell.run """C:\Windows\uuninstall.bat"" ", 0, true
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

I get the error, "The system cannot find the file specified."

**EDIT :**
The file uuninstall.bat is supposed to have 2 U's.

**EDIT2 :**
I was missing an 'n' in the program, and the question has been changed above. Thanks for answers.

Comment: I guess it is an option, but you'll have to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Try this one liner at the cmd prompt to see if this will launch your script for you.  You'll need Python installed for this to work: `python -c 'import os; os.startfile("c:\\Windows\\uuninstall.bat")'`

Comment: Can I compile this command, so it will run natively

Comment: You mean to avoid the dependency on having Python installed?  [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) makes it super simple to install

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I mean.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47096/discussion-between-the-count-and-freedom-ben)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This picture

[image]

proves that .Run runs hidden .bats without any problem. Of course, not even Windows 127 will find your `C:\Windows\uunistall.bat` when its real name is `C:\Windows\uninstall.bat`.

The idea to install Python to deal with typos is ridiculous.

**Update:**

According to your:

> EDIT: The file uuninstall.bat is supposed to have 2 U's.

the problem **is** caused by a typo: the missing n.

Comment: uuninstall.bat is the real file name, it is not a typo, the problem is that I am trying to start it hidden. It is "uuninstall.bat". Your picture does noting for me, because why is the Command Prompt shown, it is supposed to be hidden.

Comment: @TheCount did you see the missing "n" character in the file name?  Did this fix the problem?

Comment: Ok, thanks I didn't notice that. And yes, the problem was fixed.